# How to set value to the cell when hyperlink is clicked by formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a formula to set value when hyperlink is clicked in excel

This is my formula `=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!A1",A8)` I need to set value (any dummy value) in sheet2 A1

Comment: Do you need to actually jump to that cell after setting its value? Or are you just looking for a way to click a cell and populate another cell without leaving your current location?

Comment: I want to jump to cell #Sheet2!A1 after setting the value